# What did i wrong? HTML + CSS Button

Tags: html, css, button

Here's my HTML-Code:

```
<button type="button">Team</button>
```

And here my CSS Code:

```
    .button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

But on my website was just a simple HTML Button. I can't understand why. I hope for help...

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac What you state in your comment has already been discussed in the answers below.

Comment: @Helenesh I commented during review and I forgot to check if there's an answer. I've deleted it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code should be:

```
<button type="button" class="button">Team</button>
```

**OR** the CSS rule should be applied to any button, like so:

```
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: still don't work  :(

Comment: It should work. You use a `button` class in your CSS, but you don't add that class to your HTML `button` element. If it doesn't work, you're probably not including your CSS file in your HTML

Comment: no i did all right but it doesnt work... i hate it

Comment: Please share all of the HTML so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @Felaixx clear your browser cache

Comment: @Felaixx are you loading the CSS? You can check in your browser inspector if the styles load.

Comment: okay guys sorry, i just had to clear my cache